# breeze js apostraphe causing query to fail

Tags: mongodb, breeze

I'm using the breeze-mongo node module and when performing a query for an entity name which has an apostrophe the server is throwing an exception.

Query example:

```
EntityQuery.from('People')
           .where('name', '==', "brian's")
```

> Error: Unable to parse filterExpr: name eq 'brian's'
>       at parse (/node/api/node_modules/breeze-mongodb/mongoQuery.js:108:19)
>       at MongoQuery._parseUrl (/node/api/node_modules/breeze-mongodb/mongoQuery.js:29:26)
>       at new MongoQuery (/node/api/node_modules/breeze-mongodb/mongoQuery.js:21:10)
>       at getVideos (/node/api/api.js:102:19)
>       at callbacks (/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
>       at param (/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
>       at pass (/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
>       at Router._dispatch (/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
>       at Object.router (/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
>       at next (/node/api/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)

Are apostrophes not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this is a bug ... but it probably is.

We'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest Breeze 1.4.8 and the breeze-mongoDb v 0.0.6 package from npm.